# Change vertex colors in vertex buffer object

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have my model rendered with thousands of vertices and different colors. They are all stored in and rendered from a vertex buffer object though.

Is it possible in any way to change specific vertices colors without reconstructing my entire vertex buffer object with a few different colors?

Comment: Can you elaborate on whatb exactly you need? Your vertex shader doesn't have to use that attribute, and you could use other means to define the color. But that will greatly depend on how the new colors are to be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Assuming you do have your data stored in a VBO, you could update select chunks of it by first binding said object and then using glBufferSubData. Take a look here.
https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glBufferSubData.xml

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your use case, you only use a relatively small number of different colors that you assign to a large number of vertices. And you want to be able to easily update those colors without modifying the entire VBO.

You can use some form of indirection for the colors. For example:

1. Use a vertex attribute that encodes the "color index", which can be a single scalar value. This is stored in the VBO for each vertex.
2. Store the actual colors in a texture. ES 2.0 does not have 1D textures, but you can use a 2D texture where the width is the number of colors needed, and the height is 1. You can interpret this texture as a color map.
3. In the vertex shader, sample the texture using the "color index" vertex attribute as the texture coordinate. If you set the values of the vertex attribute accordingly (between 0.0 and 1.0), you can use it directly as the texture coordinate.
4. Anytime you want to update the colors, use `glTexSubImage2D()` to modify the color map texture.

This may be slower than having the colors directly in the vertex buffer, because you need a texture lookup for each vertex. On the other hand, you save memory bandwidth because your vertex data becomes smaller. It's worth a try, particularly if it makes updating the data much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a vertex buffer object just for the color data, and use another VBO for everything else.  The only VBO you'd need to modify is the color data, which should be significantly faster.  You just bind them both, making sure to set your vertex attributes from the appropriate buffer object.

I do something similar for models whose vertex positions need to animate, except in my case the positions are stored separately and "everything else" (colors, uv's, etc) is in a static VBO.